# Handle concurrent async updates to local state

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I have a series of asynchronous calls that read from a local state *S*, perform some computation based on its current value, and return a new, update value of the local state *S'*

All this happens at runtime, so I have very little control over the order of these operations. This is a simplified version of what I have.

```js
type State = {
  state: number
}

let localState: State = {
  state: 1000
}

const promiseTimeout = (time: number, value: number) => () => new Promise(
    (resolve: (n: number) => void) => setTimeout(resolve, time, value + time)
  );


const post: (n: number, currentState: State) => Promise<void> = (n, c) => promiseTimeout(n, c.state)()
  .then(res => {
    localState.state = res
    console.log(localState)
  })

post(1000, localState); // localState at call time is 1000
post(3000, localState); // localState at call time is still 1000
// when both promises resolve, the final value of localState will be 4000 instead of 5000
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8BQUoGcFIC4oA7AVwFsAjCAJwwF8MMAbCYKZgewGN5m5EEIgKRRUmbHkFEAjAAYFDJt07E8UMDU7kAljggAVHeQidS7VAApgxoSQrUaAGigA3PqTtkqtAJRiAPihLf2Qg4ggAdygABS1dfUssbGCaCBxOZlc7S2Iib0dQoNdOHQATItw2IxMzYEs0jKyIFxsTF3dmTygAaig2iF9k3wBuJgwVNXYwTjwiXPyHWhduUho04mARO23KuO09CAAeEvKgq2IVys0D-RrTc1yVgDopJF8Q5OfgAAsIYga6UC6GS2C4vH4+AgryhYigjVBUEmTWhXAA5pZwXxdsl6EMMDM8JZ5AoXFjIYJRgTZvUAMwKORknjYqFUjBAA)

This model is clearly broken, as both calls to `post` will read the same value of `localState`, while instead they should be performed sequentially.

If all calls were already determined at compile time, I could simply have something like

```js
post(1000, localState)
  .then(() => post(3000, localState)) // localState at call time is now 2000
```

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Put all promise in array in runtime and then use ```Array.reduce ``` something like ```return [
    task1,
    task2,
    task3,
].reduce((chain, task_i) => {
   
}, initialPromise) ```

Comment: Would you like to do it in a sequence, like wait 1000ms and update state, then wait 3000ms and update the state? Or you want them run in a parallel?

Comment: @UchitKumar that wouldn't work as the calls happen at runtime

Comment: @Max they need to run sequentially

Comment: @sekiro999 you can push them in array at runtime? right ?

Comment: @UchitKumar - There's no need for an array, the promise chain itself is sufficient.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, if there are more then two such post ... then we will need that approach

Comment: @UchitKumar - I'm not sure what you mean by "that approach." We don't need an array regardless of how many overlapping calls to `post` there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to have `post` hook into a promise rather than working directly on the state object. That promise could be stored in the state object itself. It starts out fulfilled with the state object. `post` updates it like this:

```
const post = (n, state) => {
    return state.promise = state.promise
        .then(state => {
            // ...do stuff here that updates (or replaces) `state`...
            return state;
        }));
};
```

Here's an example (in JavaScript, but you can add back the type annotations) using `asyncAction` (it's like your `promiseTimeout`, but without making it return a function we call immediately; not

```js
"use strict";

let localState = {
    state: 1000
};
localState.promise = Promise.resolve(localState);

// I'm not sure why this *returns* a function that we
// have to call, but...
const promiseTimeout = (time, value) => () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time, value + time));
  
const post = (n, state) => {
    return state.promise = state.promise
        .then(state => promiseTimeout(n, state.state)().then(newValue => {
            state.state = newValue;
            console.log(state.state);
            return state;
        }));
};

console.log("Running...");
post(1000, localState); // localState at call time is 1000
post(3000, localState); // localState at call time is still 1000
```

Since each call to `post` synchronously replaces the promise with a new promise, the chain is built by the calls to `post`.

Here's that in TypeScript (with a bit of a hack in one place, you can probably improve that); [link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#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-EW7lEngs3h8kKu4dEc1jXFZ-iQmZWmN8vgmrQgxH2ejMFhpizNTPGGtGuYgE2bT2MJaS5elZQAak6q5Yi8P03nm6ye-35ALTiPfJTVS3VABzCsZtuzufYVPXPSbouPb2RX12LZLlirgBEACVEcR2MRl2TL96wAHLSFQqNVASo9IoG8P6aHc+TKAS8huoyUDtJ+wQYG+eAGAAzKEwTfuowF6CcAGxEBWiVui4GQdA7R4OwhJQLBGBAA).

```
type State = {
  state: number,
  promise: Promise<State>
};

let localState: State = (() => {
    const s: Partial<State> = {
        state: 1000
    };
    // There's probably a better way to handle this than type assertions, but...
    s.promise = Promise.resolve(s as State);
    return s as State;
})();

// I'm not sure why this *returns* a function that we
// have to call, but...
const promiseTimeout = (time: number, value: number) => () => new Promise(
    (resolve: (n: number) => void) => setTimeout(resolve, time, value + time)
);

const post = (n: number, state: State): Promise<State> => {
    return state.promise = state.promise
        .then(state => promiseTimeout(n, state.state)().then(newValue => {
            state.state = newValue;
            console.log(state.state);
            return state;
        }));
};

console.log("Running...");
post(1000, localState); // localState at call time is 1000
post(3000, localState); // localState at call time is still 1000
```

---

It's worth noting that in situations like this where the state can be changed asynchronously like this, it's often worth producing a **new** state object when changing it rather than modifying the existing one — e.g., treat the state aspects as immutable.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder, this makes a lot of sense. Can you elaborate a bit more on the immutable approach? How would that be different?

Comment: @sekiro999 - Basically, instead of doing `state.x = y; return state;`, you do `return {...state, x: y};`, creating a new object rather than updating the existing one. That way, anything temporarily using a state object knows it won't change while it has it (React's state is immutable, for instance). Immutability solves some problems, creates others, so it very much depends on the wider picture. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that I have personally encountered on many occasions. My solution is to **create a queue class in charge of making sure that all Promise are executed in mutual exclusion**. I call it `PromiseQueue`:

```js
class PromiseQueue {
    constructor() {
        this._queue = new Array(); // Or an LinkedList for better performance
        this._usingQueue = false;
    }

    /**
     * Adds an element to the queue and runs the queue. It resolves when the promise has been executed and resolved.
     *
     * @param {Promise<any>} promise
     */
    add(promise) {
        const self = this;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const promiseData = {
                promise,
                resolve,
                reject,
            };
            self._queue.push(promiseData);
            self._runQueue();
        });
    }

    async _runQueue() {
        if (!this._usingQueue && this._queue.length > 0) {
            this._usingQueue = true;
            const nextPromiseData = this._queue.shift();
            const { promise, resolve, reject } = nextPromiseData;
            try {
                const result = await promise();
                resolve(result);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
            this._usingQueue = false;
            this._runQueue();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this (not tested):

```js
const myPromiseQueue = new PromiseQueue();

// This way you are making sure that the second post
// will be executed when the first one has finished
myPromiseQueue.add(async() => await post(1000, localState));
myPromiseQueue.add(async() => await post(3000, localState));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with TypeScript, so you'll have to do the conversion yourself.

You could considder adding a `queue` method to your state, which takes a callback. If the callback returns an promise it will wait for it to finish. If not the next item in the queue is immediately executed.

```js
function createQueue() {
  var promise = Promise.resolve();
  return function (fn) {
    promise = promise.then(() => fn(this));
    return promise;
  };
}

const localState = { state: 1000, queue: createQueue() };

const timeout = (...args) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ...args));
const promiseTimeout = (time, value) => timeout(time, value + time);

const post = (time, state) => state.queue(() => {
  return promiseTimeout(time, state.state).then(result => {
    state.state = result;
    console.log(state.state);
  });
});

post(1000, localState).then(() => console.log("post 1000 complete"));
post(3000, localState).then(() => console.log("post 3000 complete"));
```